# After installing word-press in cpanel it will automatically redirect to mydomain.in/wp-admin/setup-config.php

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, browser-cache

I have created a subdomain in Cpanel, then I installed WordPress, and I load my domain in chrome-browser(only) it will go to subdomian.in/wp-admin/setup-config.php and through error. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: If you are installing a fresh wordpress after connecting with database, it proceeds to setup-config.php page. Where is the issue?? pls explain more

Comment: While I loading my website keeps going to http://MyWebsite.com/wp-admin/setup-config.php

Comment: have you created the database and connected it with wordpress using wp-config.php?

Comment: yes, as per default set up in Wordpress